# bash check if a command succeeds from variable

Tags: bash

I usually check if a command succeeds or time out like this, which works just fine;

```sh
if timeout 30 someCommand; then
    echo "we're good"
else
    echo "command either failed or timed out"
fi
```

But with my new script which works with loops and variables, this simply doesn't work as expected;

```sh
wallets=/usr/local/bin/*-cli

for i in $wallets; do
    current_blocks=$(timeout 30 $i getblockcount)

    if $current_blocks; then
        echo "we're good"
    else
        echo "command either failed or timed out"
    fi
done
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: with `$( ..)` you are storing the output to some variable not the return code

Comment: Immediately after `current_blocks=$(timeout 30 $i getblockcount)` you can do `currentBlocksRetCode=$?` to get the return code, then `if [[ $currentBlocksRetcode -eq 0 ]]` then you are good.

Comment: @PS. I thought it's the same as putting the command between code quotes. @marekful this way it always returns `we're good` even if the command fails or time outs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status of the previous command is available as `$?`:

```
wallets=/usr/local/bin/*-cli

for i in $wallets; do
    current_blocks=$(timeout 30 "$i" getblockcount)
    status=$?

    if [ "$status" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "we're good"
    else
        echo "command either failed or timed out"
    fi
done
```

Or you can check the status directly:

```
if current_blocks=$(timeout 30 "$i" getblockcount)
then
  echo "It's good and the result is $current_blocks"
fi
```

Comment: Never mind, my mistake. I’d put quotes around the subshell invocations but they are not required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the normal result of `$(timeout 30 $i getblockcount)` is a bunch of JSON, you'll need to use more quotes in order to capture the string and then test it for non-emptiness.

The code fragment should look something like this:

```sh
  current_blocks="$(timeout 30 $i getblockcount)"

  if [[ -n "$current_blocks" ]]; then
    echo "we're good"
  else
    echo "Command failed or timed out"
  fi
```

Alternatively, if you only want to check the return status of the command, you can check the `$?` variable.  However, when using `timeout` with a command, the result status can be *either* the command status, or `124` from a timeout.  If the command does not manage status returns very well, testing for a consistent status might be challenging -- unless you simply want to test for a zero (success) status.

In which case, the code fragment might look like:

```sh
  current_blocks="$(timeout 30 $i getblockcount)"

  if (( $? == 0 )); then
    echo "we're good"
  else
    echo "Command failed or timed out"
  fi
```

Comment: It just returns a number on its own and nothing else.

Comment: You'll still need to use `[[ -n $current_blocks ]]` to test if the value of `current_blocks` is empty or not.   `[[ $current_blocks ]]` can also work, but relies on the variable value being syntactically "safe".